# What is the difference these JavaScript anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

These codes seem to work the same way:

Hello world

```
(
    function(a)
    {
        alert(a);
    }
)('Hello');
```

Another hello world

```
(
    function(a)
    {
        alert(a);
    }('Hello')
);
```

Is there any differences actually?

Comment: We have a habit at my job of calling this an "innie" (second option) vs. and "outie" (first option). And we prefer "outie" by and large since the parens are intended as a marker on the function to imply the execution, not contain the execution itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Given the code exactly as you've posted it, there is no *effective* difference.  Both forms construct the same anonymous function and subsequently call that function with the same argument.

Comment: Thanks! This makes me confused... and I like the first writing style anyway :)

Comment: For the record, Douglas Crockford — and by extension, JSLint — prefers the second style. ("Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.")

Comment: @davidchambers: Indeed. A completely pointless distinction for JSLint to make, in my view.